# How to fix Selenium error "WebDriverError: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process."?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run my code, selenium returns an unexplained error:

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

(async function openChromeTest() {
  try {
    let options = new chrome.Options().setChromeBinaryPath(`${__dirname}`);
    let driver = await new Builder()
                .setChromeOptions(options)
                .forBrowser('chrome')
                .build();
    await driver.get('https://www.google.com');
    await driver.quit();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})();
```

Please note that I have not added chromewebdriver.exe to my path at the default locaton. I'm trying to store it inside my node.js directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it turns out that I was very confused. I thought that setChromeBinaryPath linked to a chromedriver executable, but it actually links to a chrome executable.